# Using one scene for infinite levels

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game where there is a single scene, which will be used for an infinite number of levels until the player loses. All of my code is currently in a GameController script, and I have it so that when the level is completed, the player will press a key and integer for the level will be incremented, and the same scene will be loaded.

```cs
void Start()
{
    gamePlaying = false;
    currLevel = 0;
    BeginGame();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Return))
    {
        currLevel++;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }
}
```

I have this script and a DontDestroyOnLoad script attached to the GameController gameObject.

This currLevel variable is staying at 0 when printing to the console; however, it is updating in the inspector. What am I doing incorrectly, and is this a good way of setting up this project? Thank you!
[image]

Comment: After the level reloads, is there only one GameController object in the scene, or more than one?

Comment: Also there is no debug message in the code you posted. Add the code it’s printing from as that could easily be essential to finding the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to implement this but I would recommend to not reload the scene but have a list or container with the objects you want to destroy and when loading the next scene you destroy these and create new. You can easly make a loading screen in this time and even better pre buffer the new scene when you notice the old one is comming to an end.

So instead of reloading the scene, destroy unnecessary objects and create the onse you need. Depending on your needs you may even reuse some as the floor for example and just change the color for your level. As said that all depents on your usecase.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! I really appreciate it! This will work perfectly for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @CLC42 You are welcome. It seems as you are new on StackOverflow so I would suggest to you to accept an answer if your question is answered so noone else needs to lookup the question and then just notices its done already. (Obv only if a answere helped you). Besides that happy coding :D